# Multiple Inserts knowing the quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity-column

Let's supposed I Have a table with products like this

```
product  |  number
----------------------
aaaa     |     2
bbbb     |     3
cccc     |     1
dddd     |     4
```

It's a little more complex, but the idea is the same.

I need to return something like this

```
aaaa0001
aaaa0002
bbbb0003
bbbb0004
bbbb0005
cccc0006
dddd0007
dddd0008
dddd0009
dddd0010
```

I mean, each product the number of times specified in the column, with some kind of identificator at the end.

How can I do this ?

I thought of table variable, with identity on the Id

```
DECLARE @Codigos TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Barra Varchar(50) NOT NULL)
```

and after the inserts, do

```
select rtrim(ltrim(barra)) + right('0000' + rtrim(ltrim(cast(id as varchar(10)))),4) from @Codigos
```

but This mean that I'll have to insert for each products the number of times in the product variable, like

```
@Codigos
id     |   Barra
----------------
1      |   aaaa
2      |   aaaa
```

and I'm facing problems with that. How can I do that ? With a cursor ? That's what I thought, but I want to know if there's a better option.

Maximum will be 300 rows in original table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT product, Number, 1 RN
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT product, Number, RN + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN + 1 <= Number
)
SELECT product + RIGHT('000' + CAST(RN AS VARCHAR(3)),3) YourColumn
FROM CTE
ORDER BY product, Number
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7de9/1) for you to try.

Comment: wow, this seems that I want. Let me try it. I don't know what Option do. Nice !

Comment: @ElVieejo - The `OPTION(MAXRECURSION N)` defines the recursion level of the CTE. When the N is zero, it means "as many as it can" basically :-)